# Runnig a Windows 7 in a virtual machine (linux host) from a partition

Tags: windows, linux, virtual-machine, emulation, vmware-unity

At the moment I'm dual booting openSUSE 11.2 64bit and Windows 7 64bit. I'd like to run some windows applications from Linux without rebooting into windows or using Wine (which doesn't work on programs I need such as Visual Studio or Adobe Premiere). I'd like to have something like VMWare studios Unity function where the applications launch and look like they are running integrated with the host OS BUT I'd like it to load the OS and applications from a partition instead of a virtual image (this way what I save will persist when I start up in windows and I don't need to reinstall any of my large applications). Is there anything that makes this possible?

Hardware:
CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7 CPU 920 @ 2.67GHz
RAM: 12GB DDR3
HDD: 1.5TB split into linux/windows partitions (windows 1, windows 2, linux home, linux root, linux swap)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VirtualBox has both [seamless desktop integration](http://images.google.com/images?q=virtualbox+seamless+desktop+integration) and the ability to [boot off partitions](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/UserManual.html#id2532634).